# Which channels have clear heart beat MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a set of pulse oximetry data on different patients. Before I start any analysis, I would like to remove noisy channels (those dont show the sawtooth signal) and keep the channels with good and clear data (good channels have a sawtooth pulse). Please see an example of a good and bad channel.

The problem is the frequency of the sawtooth is not consistent in all the subjects that's why It won't be useful to use FFT.

Do you have any idea what would be the best way to separate good channels and not good channels?

Best[image]

Comment: Which is good and which is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think FFT may still be a good way for this purpose. Although the frequency varies among subject, it should be within a narrow range, like 0.5 to 2 Hz. If the FFT frequency with max amplitude is not within that range, it is likely bad signal. If it is within the range (most will), you can compare the 2nd largest amplitude component (but non-harmonic frequency of heart beat) to the main component. If it is relatively large (like 0.2 ratio, you need to figure out the threshold), it is likely a bad signal.

Comment: Thank you for your nice comment. I just did not understand very well why "but the non-harmonic frequency of heartbeat "? Could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: The amplitude at harmonic frequency is supposed to be large. So to tell if it is a bad signal, you want to avoid those frequencies.